# Why do mercury, cadmium and zinc have low melting and boiling points and elements next to them start melting at a bit higher temperatures?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, atomic-physics, atoms

I have been playing with an [online periodic table](https://www.ptable.com/) and noticed that melting/boiling points are lowest for noble gasses and nonmetals. And then it starts for metals on the left and creeps from the right side of the table. However in the 'middle' there is  [mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_%28element%29), [cadmium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadmium) and [zinc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc), which have melting points lower than [metalloids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalloid) and start to melt around the same time as metals with one electron in the outer orbital.

[image]

Why do mercury, cadmium and zinc have low melting and boiling points and elements next to them start melting at higher temperatures, but still before all other metals?

Also it seems that elements on the sides of these when temperature increases start to melt first on the left side and then on the right...

[image]

Comment: This was referenced in [a *Chemistry* question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/169007/lower-melting-points-of-zinc-cadmium-and-mercury).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i can answer this question
Zinc cadmium and mercury are d block elements i.e their last electron enters in d sublevel
.
Now most of the d-block elements are transition metals.Transition metals have intresting property that they form stong metallic bonds the reason behind that is outershell(s)electrons and inner shell (n-1)d also particpate in bonding.Due to more no of electrons particapating more no of bonds are formed as a result bonds are very strong .But zinc cadmium and mercury have completely filled d orbitals so d electrons do not particiapte in bonding so they form weak intermetallic bonds and have low melting point